# priority queue with a list container

Tags: c++, list, priority-queue

I'm trying to use a list as the underlying container for a priority queue that is holding datanode objects. It seems to work fine using a vector or deque, but i try to use a list as the underlying container and i try to push something onto the queue i get the error :

Error   3   error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_unchecked_iterator>>'

```
struct datanode{
    int depth;
    int cost;
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int ident[9];   
    int parent;
    datanode(int dep, int id[9], int);
    datanode(int dep, int id[9], int, int);
    datanode(const datanode&);
    datanode(); 
    datanode& datanode::operator=(const datanode&);
};

class NodeComparison
{
  public:
    bool operator() (datanode& da, datanode& db)
    {
        return da.cost > db.cost;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::priority_queue<datanode,list<datanode>, NodeComparison> PQueue;
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    datanode d(0,a,0);
    PQueue.push(d);
 }
```

Comment: In theory you *could* create a priority_queue that used a list as its underlying storage, but performance would be quite poor. In a priority_queue, the node at index N has children at indices 2N and 2N+1, so traversal from that node N typically progresses to one of node 2N or 2N+1. You could use `std::advance` to get to those nodes, but what you'd normally expect to be constant-complexity operations would become linear, so O(N log N) operations would end up as something like O(N*N), losing most of the reasons for using a priority queue to start with.

Comment: To be correct, `NodeComparison::operator()` should both be const and take const parameters.

Answer (score 9):

§23.6.4 [priority.queue]/p1:

> Any sequence container with random access iterator and supporting
>   operations `front()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()` can be used to
>   instantiate `priority_queue`.

`std::list` doesn't have random access iterators.